# Sys.getsizeof vaue of numpy ndarray seems too small

Tags: python, numpy

```
import sys
npArrayList = 20000 * [None]
npNdArray = np.random.normal(size = (20000, 4))
for i in xrange(20000):
    npArrayList[i] = npNdArray[i, ]
    if i == 0:
        print 'npArrayList[i].nbytes = ' + str(npArrayList[i].nbytes)

print 'npArrayList size = ' + str(sys.getsizeof(npArrayList))
print 'npNdArray.nbytes = ' + str(npNdArray.nbytes)
```

The console results are:

```
npArrayList[i].nbytes = 32
npArrayList size = 160064
npNdArray.nbytes = 640000
```

The value of 'npArrayList size' seems too small. 32 * 20000 = 640000, while the value is just 160064.

How to explain this?